# MySQL EER database model that stores download information?

Tags: mysql, database, model, eer-model

I am trying to create an EER model for a database, but I am unsure of how to go about it. I am currently learning out of a book and trying the end-of-chapter exercises and I am finding myself more and more confused.

The exercise I am trying to complete is the following:

Use MySQL Workbench to create an EER model for a database that stores information about the downloads that users make. Create the tables that are necessary to create this data structure:

Each user must have an email address, first name, and last name.

Each user can have one or more downloads.

Each download must have a filename and download date/time.

Each product can be related to one or more downloads.

Each product must have a name.

I guess you can say creating the table is my issue. I know how to create a table and open it for editing. I just don't know how I enter the information correctly. First time attempting and I am just super confused, so any tips would be great. I wish I could better explain my situation. I guess looking at all the data input fields in the table is overwhelming. Not sure how to properly name the table and how to store the information in each table.

Comment: It's hard to imagine what you're trying to do without any illustration. How many tables you want to create? Can you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65896382/edit) and include the structures of all the tables you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

For generating an EER you can go in Database menu > Reverse Engineer.
But your issue is not generating the EER, it's creating the tables of your database.

1. Each user must have an email address, first name, and last name
2. Each user can have one or more downloads. Each download must have a
   filename and download date/time.
3. Each product can be related to one or more downloads.
4. Each product must have a name.

At least you have a user, download, product tables.
I would recommend you to try modeling those tables using UML or Merise. it will allow you to manage table relationship (one to many, many to one, many to many...)

You should look here :

- https://mychartguide.com/best-entity-relationship-diagram-erd-tools/
- https://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/free-erd-tool/